# libboost_tread missing on OS X (Boost from HomeBrew)

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost, homebrew

I am on OS X and installed Boost via Homebrews `brew install boost`. Most of the libs seem to be present, but when I compile with `-lboost_thread`, I get the error:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x -o SearchServerMain SearchServerMain.cpp ErrorTolerantSearch.o SearchServer.o -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread
ld: library not found for -lboost_thread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [SearchServerMain] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

In `/usr/local/lib/` there is a `libboost_thread-mt.a`, but no `libboost_thread*`. What is the problem and what is the proper way to solve it?

Comment: Interestingly I installed boost using its own installer yesterday and I got `libboost_thread` and no `libboost_thread-mt` (on Mac)

Comment: Which installer do you mean? [Boost advises to use macports.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/quickbook/install.html)

Comment: I used boosts own install script (`./bootstrap` then `./b2`). Also it might be the case that there are only multithreaded variants of some boost libraries and the suffixes are dependent on how you actually build (see https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5443)

Comment: So, compile with `-lboost_thread-mt`. Alternatively, you could build boost with `--layout=system` to get libs without suffixes.

Comment: Nice thanks. Thats the problem. Wouldn't this be preferred to have in the brew repos?